# Программно установить приложение по умолчанию (имея ROOT права)

Tags: java, android, root

Есть приложение **А**, которое имеет ROOT права. Нужно, чтобы приложение **А** могло устанавливать себя или другие приложения как "приложение по умолчанию". Например для: приёма/отправки смс, перехода по URL и т.д.

Как это можно сделать программно (не запрашивая у пользователя)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта информация хранится в `/data/system/users/0/settings_secure.xml`. Например, дефолтное приложение для SMS хранится в элементе с ключом `sms_default_application`:

```
<setting id="85" name="sms_default_application" value="com.google.android.talk" package="com.android.settings" />
```

Подробности можно поискать в классе [Settings.Secure](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#6067)

Соответственно, если есть права root, можно программно менять этот файл.